# php-ffmpeg installation on apache2

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

Trying to run PHP-FFMPEG and after install via composer I'm currently getting this.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutableNotFoundException:
>   Executable not found, proposed : avprobe, ffprobe in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/AbstractBinary.php:159\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/Driver/FFProbeDriver.php(48):
>   Alchemy\BinaryDriver\AbstractBinary::load(Array, NULL,
>   Object(Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Configuration))\n#1
>   /var/www/html/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/FFProbe.php(226):
>   FFMpeg\Driver\FFProbeDriver::create(Object(Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Configuration),
>   NULL)\n#2
>   /var/www/html/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/FFMpeg.php(117):
>   FFMpeg\FFProbe::create(Array, NULL,
>   Object(Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache))\n#3
>   /var/www/html/starapp/test.php(4): FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create()\n#4
>   {main}\n\nNext FFMpeg\Exception\ExecutableNotFoundException: Unable
>   to load FFProbe in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/Driver/FFProbeDriver.php:50\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMp in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/Driver/FFProbeDriver.php
>   on line 50

Some people have suggested running the following:

```
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create([
    'ffmpeg.binaries' => 'usr/bin/ffmpeg',
    'ffprobe.binaries' => 'usr/bin/ffprobe',
    'timeout' => 3600, 'ffmpeg.threads' => 12
]);
```

However I have no ffmpeg/ffprobe files in usr/bin and can't seem to find them anywhere.

EDIT:

FFMpeg is installed. I rebooted the server and restarted apache2 and now the files are visible. Getting this now:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Exception\ExecutableNotFoundException:
>   Executable not found, proposed : usr/bin/ffprobe in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/alchemy/binary-driver/src/Alchemy/BinaryDriver/AbstractBinary.php:159\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/Driver/FFProbeDriver.php(48):
>   Alchemy\BinaryDriver\AbstractBinary::load(Array, NULL,
>   Object(Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Configuration))\n#1
>   /var/www/html/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/FFProbe.php(226):
>   FFMpeg\Driver\FFProbeDriver::create(Object(Alchemy\BinaryDriver\Configuration),
>   NULL)\n#2
>   /var/www/html/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/FFMpeg.php(117):
>   FFMpeg\FFProbe::create(Array, NULL,
>   Object(Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache))\n#3
>   /var/www/html/starapp/test.php(11): FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(Array,
>   NULL)\n#4 {main}\n\nNext
>   FFMpeg\Exception\ExecutableNotFoundException: Unable to load FFProbe
>   in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/Driver/FFProbeDriver.php:50\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmp in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg/src/FFMpeg/Driver/FFProbeDriver.php
>   on line 50

Comment: How did you install php-ffmpg and ffmpg

Comment: `composer require php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg` as on here https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

Comment: THats the library that links PHP to FFMPEG.... Did you also install FFMPEG itself?

Comment: As it says on that github page **This library requires a working FFMpeg install. You will need both FFMpeg and FFProbe binaries to use it**

Comment: FFMpeg is installed. I rebooted the server and restarted apache2 and now the files are visible. Getting another error now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was the paths

```
'ffmpeg.binaries' => 'usr/bin/ffmpeg',
'ffprobe.binaries' => 'usr/bin/ffprobe'
```

Whereas:

```
'ffmpeg.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffmpeg',
'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffprobe'
```

Is working.